# react-navigation: disable modal animation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is it possible to disable the modal animation of React Navigation?

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const params = navigation.state.params || {};

    return {
      headerLeft: (
        <Button
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('MyModal')}
          title="Info"
          color="#fff"
        />
      ),
      /* the rest of this config is unchanged */
    };
  };

  /* render function, etc */
}

class ModalScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>This is a modal!</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
          title="Dismiss"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const MainStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
    },
    Details: {
      screen: DetailsScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    /* Same configuration as before */
  }
);

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: MainStack,
    },
    MyModal: {
      screen: ModalScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);
```

Examples are obtained from React Native official documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/modal.html

Comment: You can add any transition animation with `transitionConfig` prop. [Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/transitioner.html) [API](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#stacknavigatorconfig)

Comment: can you give example? I want to remove animation, not add.

Comment: I can't give an example because I'm on mobile but you can try to set duration to 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution

Use `transitionSpec` in `transitionConfig` for custom screen transition. And make transition duration to Zero. 
[Official](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#modal-stacknavigator-with-custom-screen-transitions)

Example (Not tested)

```
const ModalNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Main: { screen: Main },
    Login: { screen: Login },
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
    mode: 'modal',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: false,
    },
    transitionConfig: () => ({
      transitionSpec: {
        duration: 0,
      },
    })
...
```

Comment: Almost perfect, just missed the trailing close brackets.

Comment: @Raptor I added. >_^

Comment: just use`animationEnabled: false`.

Answer (score 3):

Disable the animation by adding "animation: 'none'" in navigation options:

```
<AuthStackNavigator.Screen
    name="MyModalScreen"
    component={MyModalScreen}
    options={{
        presentation: 'transparentModal',
        headerShown: false,
        animation: 'none'  // here
    }}
/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: You should add explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite what you want, but you can use the built in `Modal` component rendered the screen instead. The benefit of doing this is that the `Modal` component has an [animationtype prop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal#animationtype) that you can set to "none" to get an animation-less modal.